# Установкой расширения через Composer

Tags: yii2, composer, token

После нажатия на установку расширения через Composer в Yii2 выскакивает следующее:

[image: composer update]

В конечном пути C:\Users\programmer6\AppData\Roaming\Composer\ нет никакого файла auth.json. Я сгенерировал токен и создал файл с таким именем, но мне выдается ошибка при чтении этого файла, видимо в нем должна быть какая-то структура. Где мне узнать как правильно записать токен в этот файл?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все оказалось довольно просто. Нужно было вставить токен в консоль и нажать клавишу Enter. Просто тут оказалось точно также как и при вводе пароля, не будет видно что вы его вставляете. Так что не пугайтесь, вставили, приняли и все.